# Android: In App Purchase server API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

The purchase subscription API's allow users to get, cancel, defer, refund and revoke a purchase/subscription.  Is there a way to restrict it to read only (only get API).

This is required to restrict the server to only track/validate the in app purchase and not allow it to do other write operations like cancel, defer etc.